# Why my program in c keeps looping and not storing values in memory?

Tags: c, for-loop

I am a beginner in C programming and I am stuck in my little program .

I just wanna make a list from which I ask users to select a number from that list. Then the program should do what it should be done.

My list is:

1. Create a table
2. Max & Min Number Checking
3. Negative & Positive Number Checking
4. Ascending Order
5. Descending order
6. Exit

I couldn't start correctly! When I first press 1 to create the table, the program keeps looping again and again!!

I want my program to ask me for some values then take my value and draw me a table and then store these values temporary in memory, so that I can execute the rest of commands from my list.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int t[100],n,a,f,s=0,i,max,min,m,l;
    {
        printf("Welcome to My simple Math Program in C language  \n");

        printf("1:Create a table\n 2:Max&Min Number Checking\n 3:Negative&Positive Number Checking\n 4:Ascending Order\n 5:Descending ordert\n 6:Exit\n ");

        printf("Please Choose a number from the list"  );

        scanf("%d",&a);

         while(a!=6){
            switch(a){
                case 1:printf("Please Enter The Length Of Your Table ");
                    scanf("%d",&n);
                    printf("Please Enter Your Table Elements ");

                    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                        scanf("%d",&t[i]);
                    }

                    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                        printf("%d ",t[i]);
                    }
                    break;

                case 3:
                    if(t[i]<0){
                        printf("This Number is Negative %d",t[i]);
                    }
                    else if(t[i]==0){
                        printf("This Number is nulle %d",t[i]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("This Number is Positive %d",t[i]);
                    }
                    ;break;

                    case 6:
                        break;
                }
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your editor has weird empty line habits. Please delete most of them for making a more readable post.

Comment: Please read up on and apply indentation.

Answer (score 2):

Your scanf() statement is outside your while loop so it is only executed once.  You need something like this:

```
do
{
    scanf("%d",&a);
    ...rest of code
} while (a!=6)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply . should i put all of my code inside the area you have mentioned ?

Comment: I would upvote your answer, had you not used a `do` / `while` statement. You could write this instead: `for(;;) { print_the_message(); if (scanf("%d", &a) != 1 || a == 6) break; ... }`

Answer (score 0):

You should print the message and read the option inside the main loop:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int t[100], n, a, f, s = 0, i, max, min, m, l;

    printf("Welcome to My simple Math Program in C language\n");

    for (;;) {
        printf("1: Create a table\n"
               "2: Max&Min Number Checking\n"
               "3: Negative&Positive Number Checking\n"
               "4: Ascending Order\n"
               "5: Descending ordert\n"
               "6: Exit\n");
        printf("Please Choose a number from the list: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &a) != 1) /* invalid input */
            break;
        if (a == 6)
            break;

        switch (a) {
          case 1:
            printf("Please Enter The Length Of Your Table ");
            if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
                break;
            if (n > 100)
                n = 100;
            printf("Please Enter Your Table Elements: ");
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                scanf("%d", &t[i]);
            }
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                printf("%d ",t[i]);
            }
            break;

          case 3:
            i = 0;
            if (t[i] < 0) {
                printf("This Number is Negative %d\n", t[i]);
            } else
            if (t[i] == 0) {
                printf("This Number is null %d\n", t[i]);
            } else {
                printf("This Number is Positive %d",t[i]);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```